# Filefield is not displayed on foreign key field on popup in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

File field from this model is not displayed on the popup form on a foreign key field in django admin.
My model is:

```py
class NationalId(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    not_registered_user = models.OneToOneField(NotRegisteredUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=False)
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    date_verified = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_expired = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'scanned image'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.national_id
```

And the popup shown is
[image]

Comment: can you share a code of NationalIdAdmin?

Comment: Yes, I've only this line: admin.site.register(NationalId,)